# British citizen flying from UK to Malaysia, then to Thailand. Will I need a visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, uk-citizens, thailand, malaysia

I am a British citizen flying from the UK (Manchester) to Malaysia (Kuala Lumpur). I will stay in KL for 4 days, then on to Thailand for 14 days, then back to Malaysia the day before I fly home to the UK.

Will I need a visa to visit Thailand or to regain entry to Malaysia?

Comment: Seen as though I cant answer because it's on hold. You will not need a visa. You can visit Malaysia 3 months visa free and Thailand 30 days visa free. You are only permitted to visit Thailand twice in a 12 month period, any more you need a visa.

Comment: @BritishSam The twice per year restriction only applies to land entries

Answer (score 2):

No.

I am British and visited both places this year and got entry on arrival.

Thailand is actually Visa free for Brits.

Comment: Accept the answer then please ;)

Answer (score 2):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

**Thailand**

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a British passport with nationality British Citizen for a maximum stay of 30 days.

**Malaysia**

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a British passport for a maximum stay of 90 days

So no, you don't need visas.